# How to update List of objects in scala

Tags: scala

I have two `Seq[User]` and I need to update one of them. If the array element has the same Id, I must update the element, if not, add a new
My code:

```
  case class User(id: String, name: String)

  val oldUsers = Seq(User("1", "Test1"), User("2", "Test2"), User("8", "Test8"), User("9", "Test9"))

  val newUsers = Seq(User("1", "UpdatedTest1"), User("10", "UpdatedTest10"))

  val full = oldUsers.toSet ++ newUsers.toSet

  val n = full.flatMap{ o =>
    newUsers.filterNot(_.id.equals(o.id))
  }
```

But it works incorrect. As a result i want to get:
`Seq(User(1,UpdatedTest1), User(2,Test2), User(9,Test9), User(10,UpdatedTest10), User(8,Test8))`

Answer (score 2):

The error is that you are filtering after the concatenation whereas you should filter before that.

```
// Case classes must be final.
final case class User(id: String, name: String)

// Prefer Lists or other concrete collection, instead of Seq.
val oldUsers = List(User("1", "Test1"), User("2", "Test2"), User("8", "Test8"), User("9", "Test9"))
val newUsers = List(User("1", "UpdatedTest1"), User("10", "UpdatedTest10"))

val idsToRemove = newUsers.iterator.map(_.id).toSet

val result = oldUsers.filterNot(u => idsToRemove.contains(u.id)) reverse_::: newUsers
// result: List[User] = List(User(9,Test9), User(8,Test8), User(2,Test2), User(1,UpdatedTest1), User(10,UpdatedTest10))
```

You can see it running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/oWcU89yKTWiu0nCWszGwWQ/3).

Answer (score 2):

1. First remove users from oldUsers list which are present in newUsers list
2. Concat list(filtered) from 1 with newUsers

```scala
val result = oldUsers.filterNot(u => newUsers.exists(_.id == u.id)) ++ newUsers
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `foldLeft` that you can further optimize with mutable indexed data structures if your program is heavy on updates:

```
final case class User(id: String, name: String)

val oldUsers = Seq(User("1", "Test1"), User("2", "Test2"), User("8", "Test8"), User("9", "Test9"))

val newUsers = Seq(User("1", "UpdatedTest1"), User("10", "UpdatedTest10"))

val updatedUsers = newUsers.foldLeft(oldUsers)((oldUsers, user) => {
  oldUsers.indexWhere(user.id == _.id) match {
    case -1    => user +: oldUsers // if a user is not found, indexWhere will return -1
    case index => oldUsers.updated(index, user)
  }
})
// List(User(10,UpdatedTest10), User(1,UpdatedTest1), User(2,Test2), User(8,Test8), User(9,Test9))
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to understand is that by default case classes have generated `equals` and `hashCode` methods that check all class fields(in your case not only `id` but `name` too. So, your code

```
val full: Set[User] = List(User("a", "b")).toSet ++ List(User("a", "c"))
```

goes to `Set(User(a,b), User(a,c))` (have you noticed that when you concat two collections, the exact type of result is inferred by first collection?)

The second thing I'd like to advise is to use some hash data structure here. With the big datasets it could give an advantage in comparing with two nested loops.
So, the solution could look like:

```
case class User(id: String, name: String)
val oldUsers =
  Seq(User("1", "Test1"), User("2", "Test2"), User("8", "Test8"), User("9", "Test9"))
val newUsers = Seq(User("1", "UpdatedTest1"), User("10", "UpdatedTest10"))

val oldAsMap = oldUsers.map(user => user.id -> user).toMap
val newAsMap = newUsers.map(user => user.id -> user).toMap

val ids = oldAsMap.keySet ++ newAsMap.keySet

val result = ids.map(id => newAsMap.getOrElse(id, oldAsMap(id))).toSeq
```